# objective c- facebook FBSDK upgraded but xcode still using old one when compile

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

i have added new **FBSDK 4.9.1** with my old code but when i check SDK version it shows **4.4.0** in console i dont know why it is not using **4.9.1**

steps i have done.

1.download latest sdk from [facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios)

2.import to my code and set framework path as per facebook guideline

3.run the code with

`NSLog( @"### running FB sdk version: %@", [FBSDKSettings sdkVersion] );`

to check sdk version but still shows 4.4.0

> 2016-02-03 15:49:36.243 Check-IN[1522:198182] ### running FB sdk version: 4.4.0